# Sharing Android instrumentation tests between modules

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

Our Android app code is setup is like below:

```
Project
----Module1
----Module2
----Common UI library module
----Common SDK module
```

Module 1 and Module 2 are built into separate apks and published separately. They however share/extend a great deal of UI that are in the library module. Currently we have instrumentation tests inside each module, which means we have to duplicate tests for the same screens (defined in the UI module) under both Module 1 and Module 2. Is there a way to strip out the instrumentation tests from the specific modules and have a separate test module? I would ideally like to have shared tests where I can specify through command line something along the lines of: "Run test suite T against the test apk for Module 1" or "Run test suite T against the test apk for Module 2.

Any suggestions on how to do this is appreciated.